# How can I add to a type that contains an integer inside a Result of a discriminated union?

Tags: f#

I'm working on a single case discriminated union with a module to create instances of the type and return a Result of either Ok if the input was valid or Error otherwise. Here is what I have so far.

```ml
type ErrorMessage = string
type NonNegativeInt = private NonNegativeInt of int

module NonNegativeInt =
    
    let create (inputInt:int) : Result<NonNegativeInt, ErrorMessage> =
        if inputInt >= 0 then
            Ok (NonNegativeInt inputInt)
        else
            Error ("inputInt must be >= 0")
      
    let value (NonNegativeInt intVal) = intVal
```

I would like to add an integer to an instance of this type using the create function so it will block negatives. I've got the first test working this way.

```ml
[<Fact>]
member this.``NonNegativeInt test`` () =
    
    let nonNegativeResult = NonNegativeInt.create 5
    
    let newNonNegativeResult = match nonNegativeResult with
                               | Ok result ->
                                   let intVal = NonNegativeInt.value result
                                   let newIntVal = intVal + 1
                                   NonNegativeInt.create newIntVal
                               | Error _ ->
                                   nonNegativeResult
            
    match newNonNegativeResult with
    | Ok result ->
        Assert.Equal(6, NonNegativeInt.value result)
    | Error _ ->
        Assert.Fail("Error creating new NonNegativeInt")
```

This is pretty much unusable this way. Is there a more concise way to accomplish this task without all the unwrapping, wrapping, and pattern matching? Is Result.bind the way to go?

### Update 1 Trying Result.bind

This is a better, but still feels a bit clumsy. Maybe the `NonNegativeInt` module needs another function besides create and value to make this easier.

```ml
[<Fact>]   
member this.``NonNegativeInt test2`` () =

    let nni1 = NonNegativeInt.create 5

    let nni2 = nni1
               |> Result.bind (fun x -> NonNegativeInt.create ((NonNegativeInt.value x) + 1))
    
    let expectedResult = NonNegativeInt.create 6
    
    Assert.Equal(expectedResult, nni2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion 1

You could use a computation builder to make the code cleaner:

```ml
type ResultBuilder() =
    member _.Return(x) = Ok x
    member _.ReturnFrom(res : Result<_, _>) = res
    member _.Bind(res, f) = Result.bind f res

let result = ResultBuilder()
```

Then your example becomes:

```ml
let test () =
    result {
        let! nni = NonNegativeInt.create 5
        return! NonNegativeInt.create (nni.Value + 1)
    }

test () |> printfn "%A"   // Ok NonNegativeInt 6
```

I also added a member to make it easier to access a NonNegativeInteger's value:

```ml
type NonNegativeInt =
    private NonNegativeInt of int
    with
    member this.Value =
        let (NonNegativeInt n) = this in n
```

### Suggestion 2

Having an NNI type and then wrapping it in a Result is like wearing both a belt and suspenders. To simplify things further, you could get rid of the NNI type entirely, and just keep the validation logic:

```ml
module NonNegativeInt =
    
    let create (inputInt:int) : Result<int, ErrorMessage> =
        if inputInt >= 0 then
            Ok inputInt
        else
            Error ("inputInt must be >= 0")

let test () =
    result {
        let! n = NonNegativeInt.create 5
        return! NonNegativeInt.create (n + 1)
    }

test () |> printfn "%A"   // Ok 6
```

### Suggestion 3

Alternatively, you could keep the NNI type and trust the caller to use it with valid values (without wrapping in a Result). This is what [FsCheck](https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/blob/fc7d76ab488f4861dc3f376dc2cbff78cb0336d3/src/FsCheck/Arbitrary.fs#L22-22) does, for example:

```ml
///Represents an int >= 0
type NonNegativeInt = NonNegativeInt of int with
    member x.Get = match x with NonNegativeInt r -> r
    override x.ToString() = x.Get.ToString()
    static member op_Explicit(NonNegativeInt i) = i
```

Comment: This is great! It's going to take a minute to grasp this. The computation expression is amazing. I need to really buckle down and get over my mental block on those. They're probably not as difficult as I image. Can the result computation expression be used inside of some other computation expression like task{}?

Comment: Computation expressions really are great. You can use one inside another, but if you're going to be working with `Task<Result<_, _>>`, it's probably better to use a builder specifically for that type. There's one [here](https://demystifyfp.gitbook.io/fstoolkit-errorhandling/taskresult/ce), but I haven't tried it.